# Why doesn't the String method concat work in a for loop?

Tags: java

I am in the process of learning. I will be using StringBuilder for this problem, but this is bothering me.

The objective is to make a String from an array of Strings. The concat method doesn't work but the addition operator works.

This works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr= {"1","2","3"};
    String output ="";
    for(String str: arr)
        output+=str;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

But this doesn't concat method doesn't allow me to concatenate a String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr= {"1","2","3"};
    String output ="";
    for(String str: arr)
        output.concat(str);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: In a loop case like this it may make sense to use a StringBuilder which, unlike a String, *is* mutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `concat` method doesn't mutate the current String, but in fact returns a new `String` containing the result.

Use it like this:

```
output = output.concat(str);
```

[`String.concat` documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @Kayla Strings' immutability means *specifically* that you have to assign the return value. Glad you learned something new. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `return` of `concat`.

```
for(String str: arr)
    output = output.concat(str);
```

The method `concat()` returns a `String` of the concatenated results you just need to assign it to `output`.